# Error when compiling some simple c++ code

Tags: c++, macos, linker-errors

I try to compile this cpp code on osx lion but I get an error.

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    { 
        cout << "hi"; 
        cout << endl; 
    } 

    return 0; 
}
```

To compile:

```
cc main.cpp
```

Error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      _main in ccBdbc76.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in ccBdbc76.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      _main in ccBdbc76.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))", referenced from:
      _main in ccBdbc76.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in ccBdbc76.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___tcf_0 in ccBdbc76.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: That's a linker problem. How are you linking?

Comment: I'm new to cpp, I don't really understand your question. :

Comment: What instructions did you use to compile and link? What compiler?

Comment: I'm compiling with "cc". Exemple: "cc main.cpp"

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc - that's your problem.  Check out my answer.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Normally this sort of failure happens when compiling your C++ code by invoking the C front-end.  The `gcc` you execute understands and compiles the file as C++, but doesn't link it with the C++ libraries.  Example:

```
$ gcc example.cpp 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      _main in ccLTUBHJ.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in ccLTUBHJ.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      _main in ccLTUBHJ.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))", referenced from:
      _main in ccLTUBHJ.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)in ccLTUBHJ.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___tcf_0 in ccLTUBHJ.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$ g++ example.cpp 
$
```

As you can see, using `g++` makes the problems go away.  The same behaviour (with slightly different messages) occurs if you use `clang` (which I'd recommend):

```
$ clang example.cpp 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in cc-IeV9O1.o
  "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in cc-IeV9O1.o
  "std::cout", referenced from:
      _main in cc-IeV9O1.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      _main in cc-IeV9O1.o
  "std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)", referenced from:
      _main in cc-IeV9O1.o
  "std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))", referenced from:
      _main in cc-IeV9O1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
$ clang++ example.cpp 
$
```

As you can see in the `clang` error message, you could use `-v` to see the linker invocation to see what's going wrong.  It would show you this link line:

```
"/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 
    -macosx_version_min 10.6.8 -o a.out -lcrt1.10.6.o
    /var/folders/zl/zlZcj24WHvenScwjPFFFQE+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-hdOL8Z.o
    -lSystem /Developer/usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

Or something like it - as you can see, it's linking the C runtime, not C++, and also doesn't have the C++ libraries.  Using `clang++` the link line is:

```
"/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64
     -macosx_version_min 10.6.8 -o a.out -lcrt1.10.6.o 
     /var/folders/zl/zlZcj24WHvenScwjPFFFQE+++TI/-Tmp-/cc-wJwxjP.o 
     /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib -lSystem
     /Developer/usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

As you can see, `libstdc++` is included, and presto - no link errors.

Comment: Oops! I forgot to add my `other.c` file to the `clang` command filenames argument. I just did `clang main.c`. Doing `clang main.c other.c` worked. (I have `#include "other.h"` at the top of `main.c`.

Comment: If you're using objc++, any included .m file needs to be renamed to .mm such that it is compiled correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
g++ main.cpp
```

This way it should work, at least using OS X

Answer (score 4):

Use CC command (uppercase) to compile C++ and link to standard C++ library.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with OSX LION. However, in the strictest sense, the errors described are not caused by the compiler, but by the linker. It seems as if the standard library is not being linked.

Answer (score 2):

As of Yosemite (10.10.1), I've found that `gcc` with the `-lc++` flag also works:

```
gcc -lc++ main.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

If using clang on OS X , try :

```
clang++ simple_cpp_program_file.cpp -o simple_cpp_program_file.out
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution that works on macOs Sierra:

There are two implementations of the standard C++ library available on OS X: libstdc++ and libc++. They are not binary compatible and libMLi3 requires libstdc++.

On 10.8 and earlier libstdc++ is chosen by default, on 10.9 libc++ is chosen by default. To ensure compatibility with libMLi3, we need to choose libstdc++ manually.

To do this, add -stdlib=libstdc++ to the linking command.

Answer (score 0):

Is this GCC on Windows (MinGW) or Linux? On MinGW you need the parameters `-lmingw32 -enable-auto-import`. Linux might needs something similar, `-enable-auto-import` is most likely needed.

Comment: The OP's question says 'osx lion'.

Answer (score 0):

So the error ld: library not found for -lstdc++ is where the actual error lies.

To fix this, open the folder

open /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/

Run the package macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg

Then gem install mini_racer works!

This issue may not be only related to mini_racer as it could affect any gem that compiles an extension.。