# GCC error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: gcc, homebrew

Today I experimented with GCC/G++ :(

I was not sure which c++ standards were installed (completely new to c++), so I updated gcc to the latest version with brew (`brew install gcc --HEAD`) but now it seems that the latest version is unfortunately unstable for my setup.

clang version before: Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)

clang version after: Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27) but with following error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

OS: macOS@11.0.1

Does anyone knows how to solve this? I am still able to use g++, only gcc is not working at all, no matter of `-std=` flag or not. Is installing the latest stable version a proper solution or will this make it worse ;-) ?

```
gcc helloworld.cc -v -o out
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1"
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx11.0.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name helloworld.cc -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mframe-pointer=all -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-sdk-version=11.0 -target-cpu penryn -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 609.6 -v -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -stdlib=libc++ -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir "/Users/user/x/y/z/zz/zzz" -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 167 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fobjc-runtime=macosx-11.0.0 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /var/folders/rq/6cbshbgd2bdbpl3tqf7cg27c0000gn/T/helloworld-3e60f0.o -x c++ helloworld.cc
clang -cc1 version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27) default target x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -platform_version macos 11.0.0 11.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o out -L/usr/local/lib /var/folders/rq/6cbshbgd2bdbpl3tqf7cg27c0000gn/T/helloworld-3e60f0.o -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/12.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(unsigned long, char) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::put(char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::flush()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::endl<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ios_base::setstate(unsigned int) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "___cxa_call_unexpected", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in helloworld-3e60f0.o
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in helloworld-3e60f0.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: When asking about build errors, always copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output. And if you build your own project then please also include the command used for building (or flags/options used, or other relevant build environment information). Preferably also include a [mcve] as well.

Comment: I thought that the output in verbose mode might be better for GitHub or so because its too long for stackoverflow. I will update that :-) Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you use the C language front-end program, not the C++ front-end program. Build C++ programs with `g++` instead. The main difference is that `g++` will automatically link with the C++ library, which `gcc` will not.

Comment: Or, since you're really using the Clang alias, use `clang++` directly.

Comment: Thanks for your help! :) I can still use g++ for compiling which is enough. Before I updated to the latest version it worked fine, so I thought it might cause errors for other applications using it and just want to undo it.

Comment: Note that you're not actually using GCC, but rather Clang. The `gcc` (or `g++`) command you use is just an alias. Perhaps the alias was set up differently before?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when compiling some simple c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533321/error-when-compiling-some-simple-c-code)

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot compile C++ code with `gcc` or `clang`. You need to use a C++ compiler, such as `clang++` or `g++`.
2. Check what you are actually running. If you use `gcc file.c`, at least run:

   `type gcc`

to se what you are running. If it's `/bin/something` or `/usr/bin/something` or `/Applications/something`, it's from Apple. If it's `/usr/local/something` it's **homebrew**.

3. If you are using **homebrew**, firstly check you are doing everything right by running:

   `brew doctor`

And secondly, make sure your PATH starts with `/usr/local/bin` which is where **homebrew** puts its binaries:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. 2. /usr/bin/gcc 3. a) Xcode command line tools are not up to date b) "config scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories. `./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking." c) "Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include." d) brew does not support macOS@11 e) CLT does not support macOS@11 f) Broken symlinks

Comment: So if `type gcc` reports `/usr/bin/gcc` you are wasting your time updating anything in **homebrew** because you are using an Apple compiler. If your Xcode is out of date, update it. If you are writing C++, use a C++ compiler...