# Error : ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64, clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: macos, terminal, keychain, clang++, command-line-tool

Note : I'm on Mac OS X Ventura 13, M1 Mac 2020.

This Problem is arising recently, although code itself is very simple

```
int main(){
    int a, in; cin>>in;
    for(a=in;a!=0;a=a/10){
       cout<<a<<"\n";
    }
}
```

[The Code in file named "test.cpp"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4j3T.png)

And after I solved my problem of keychain access where it will ask the password and it wasn't letting me connect my git account to my VS Code. Then in the process I accidentally clicked "Reset to Default" and had to put all of the passwords back, which I think is related to this current problem in which my code which I was able to run in the terminal earlier but now can not, unexpectedly the code runner was deleted but even after downloaded it and refreshing the code it will not run in the integrated terminal, and even after going to the path on external terminal and putting gcc test.cpp it is not running.
Main reason why I think why keychain access may be at fault is because I also get this
zsh: permission denied: message when I try to run the file with the shortcut key of ctrl + option + N but it complies if I just click the run button but it will run in the debug config and will not grant me a way so that I can input a value.

```
~/Desktop/Shubh Coding/C++ Mac/Array: gcc test.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in test-2db6d0.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in test-2db6d0.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(unsigned long, char) in test-2db6d0.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in test-2db6d0.o
  "std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator>>(int&)", referenced from:
      _main in test-2db6d0.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test-2db6d0.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::~sentry()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test-2db6d0.o
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)", referenced from:
      _main in test-2db6d0.o
  "std::__1::cin", referenced from:
      _main in test-2db6d0.o
  "std::__1::cout", referenced from:
      _main in test-2db6d0.o
  "std::__1::ctype<char>::id", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in test-2db6d0.o
  "std::__1::locale::~locale()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in test-2db6d0.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrow()", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test-2db6d0.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::clear(unsigned int)", referenced from:
      std::__1::ios_base::setstate(unsigned int) in test-2db6d0.o
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in test-2db6d0.o
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test-2db6d0.o
      ___clang_call_terminate in test-2db6d0.o
  "___cxa_call_unexpected", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::failed() const in test-2db6d0.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test-2db6d0.o
  "___cxa_end_catch", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test-2db6d0.o
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::__put_character_sequence<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, unsigned long) in test-2db6d0.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__1::ios_base&, char) in test-2db6d0.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::failed() const in test-2db6d0.o
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::ostreambuf_iterator(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in test-2db6d0.o
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in test-2db6d0.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[This is the image of the output to the command typed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDYYR.jpg)
I've tried searching it on stack enough that I have to post my own question, also my sync on Brave is not working because of my stupid mistake.

Note: I also have kinda same error in processing the C file, with lots of text printed on the terminal but i do not code in C anymore, idk if they are related because was able coding in CPP regardless until now.

I've tried giving permission to terminal, by going to the system setting and in the privacy heading going to full disk access and selecting terminal in the list, also selecting the vs code, but it doesn't work, I have also tried going to the same menu and under the developer tools and clicking terminal over there also.
On the related problems asked on this site the answers are usually unique to the given problem and they do not apply to my problem, I don't understand the message that is written in the terminal after I type "gcc test.cpp" click return. I know how to navigate to the correct directory so thats why IK that wrong directory is not the problem.

PS: I hope all of this makes sense because I know my english is not good and I don't want to waste the time of the person wanting to solve this problem. If you want more clearity, I'll provide with more screenshots.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have ‘clang’ running- that is a C compiler.  Use ‘clang++’ instead.

Comment: Or g++ instead of gcc

Comment: @Dragonthoughts
Thank You for showing interest in my problem, my exact problem is that my code in C++ that was running perfectly fine for many days and now it is not, I'm a new Mac OS user as well and I'm not able to get all the nuances that one should get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when compiling some simple c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533321/error-when-compiling-some-simple-c-code)

Comment: No, The problem is still there, it is something really low level, Maybe its something due to my compiler settings, the problem is closely related to some null pointer reference in the deep low level cpp file.

Answer (score 0):

You have called the `gcc` C compiler but given it C++ code.  You should try calling the C++ compiler instead, `g++`

Comment: I have tried doing this but it will only compile the code or that is what I think it does because whenever i type and enter "g++ test.cpp" then it will go to the next line and nothing will happen. I will try that now as advised.

Comment: Should I send the screenshot to you of the output that appears after I type it?

Comment: Did it generate any output.. usually we specify the file/path of the output file when using compilation.

Comment: It did not produce any output to my code but went to the next instance in the terminal,

Comment: Ok, that means it’s exiting clean…  what seems to be the issue at this time?

Comment: that it do not ask for input or produce any output and what do you mean by path of the output file?

Comment: Why would a compiler ask for input when you have provided an input file?  What output are you expecting?

Comment: I think, it should ask the value for variable "in" and then provide the output in the terminal. like it does in the VS code terminal

Comment: However, compilation does not cause the code to execute.  You would have to call the resultant assembled binary object in order for the code to execute.

Comment: Okay got it, I guess I have to learn what command there is to do that, because VS code used to do it for me whenever I would click the run button. Thank you very much for your explanation and replies to my silly questions.