# Linker error despite having makefile on Mac

Tags: c++, makefile

**This is the code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include "SFML/Window.hpp"
#include "SFML/System.hpp"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

       sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML Application");
       sf::CircleShape shape;
       shape.setRadius(40.f);
       shape.setPosition(100.f, 100.f);

        shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Cyan);
       while (window.isOpen())
       {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
       }

return 0;
}
```

**This is the makefile:**

```
output: run.o
    g++ run.o -o output

run.o: run.cpp
    g++ -c run.cpp

OBJECTS = run.o
LIBS = -L lib -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio
CC = g++

prog:   $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -o prog


clean:
    rm *.o
```

**This is the Linker error:**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "sf::WindowBase::pollEvent(sf::Event&)", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
  "sf::CircleShape::setRadius(float)", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
  "sf::CircleShape::CircleShape(float, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
  "sf::RenderStates::Default", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
  "sf::RenderTarget::draw(sf::Drawable const&, sf::RenderStates const&)", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
  "sf::RenderTarget::clear(sf::Color const&)", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
  "sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, sf::String const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
  "sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow()", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
  "sf::Transformable::setPosition(float, float)", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
  "sf::Color::Cyan", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
  "sf::Color::Color(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
  "sf::Shape::setFillColor(sf::Color const&)", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
  "sf::Shape::~Shape()", referenced from:
      sf::CircleShape::~CircleShape() in run.o
  "sf::String::String(char const*, std::__1::locale const&)", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
  "sf::Window::close()", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
  "sf::Window::display()", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
  "sf::VideoMode::VideoMode(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
  "sf::WindowBase::isOpen() const", referenced from:
      _main in run.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [output] Error 1
```

**How to resolve?**

Comment: Mention the include path in the compilation command.

Comment: @kiner_shah i am noob. how to do it?

Comment: Similar to this problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533321/error-when-compiling-some-simple-c-code

Comment: Try moving `$(LIBS)` to *after* `-o prog` in the linker command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not specify a target, make will build the **first target** in your Makefile, in this case `output`.
However, the recipe for `output` does not specify any of the flags you need.

You can either remove the rule for `output`, move the rule for `prog` and all its variables to the top of the Makefile, or you can add a single line at the top:

```
all: prog
```

Unrelated: Make has built-in rules for building .o files from .cpp files, so you can drop the rule for `run.o`. This also allows you to specify the optimization level and other compilation flags by mucking with the `CXXFLAGS` variable.

Comment: @verdy if this solution worked for you can you mark it as an accepted answer?